# How can I get the data from WSDL file using SOAP1.2

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl

I am working for a project and I have to get data from a WSDL url
**http://80.127.98.91:6060/BonnenExterneApp?wsdl**

Our webservice uses SOAP1.2 and I am using Nusoap0.9.5 library to get the data. But I am getting an error like

```
RESULT = Array
(
    [faultcode] => e:VersionMismatch
    [faultstring] => received something that is not a SOAP Envelope
)

Constructor error

e:VersionMismatch: received something that is not a SOAP Envelope
```

The Code I am using to call web service is

```
<?php
require_once('lib/nusoap.php');

//Declare some paramaters for our soapclient. Need to make sure its set to soap 1.2
$params  = array("soap_version"=> SOAP_1_2,
                "trace"=>1,
                "exceptions"=>0,
                );


$iboks = new nusoap_client('http://80.127.98.91:6060/BonnenExterneApp?wsdl', $params);
$result = $iboks->call('AW_SYS01_01_Login', array("piUserId" => "myusername", "piPassword" => "mypassword"));

echo "<pre>RESULT = ".print_r($result, true)."</pre>";
$err = $iboks->getError();

if ($err) {
   echo '<h2>Constructor error</h2><pre>' . $err . '</pre>';
   exit();
}
?>
```

Tell me what I am doing wrong, I have tested this url from a online tools. Online tools are giving the answers but I want to get the data from PHP.

Tool which I am using is
**http://soapclient.com/soaptest.html**

For security reason the username and passwords are changed here.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer for my problem.
URL is just for example but my exact url is also working now.

I was using the nusoap for wsdl1.2 but the nusoap is not providing the support for the wsdl1.2 so I choosed the PHP Soap Client.
**http://php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php**

And My code is now looking as

```
<?php
$client = new SoapClient("http://www.webservicex.com/globalweather.asmx?wsdl", array('soap_version'   => SOAP_1_2));
$something =  $client->GetCitiesByCountry(array("CountryName"=>"India"));

echo "<pre>"; print_r($something);
die();
?>
```

And the output is like

```
  stdClass Object
(
    [GetCitiesByCountryResult] => 
  British Indian Ocean TerritoryDiego Garcia

  IndiaAhmadabad

  IndiaAkola

  IndiaAurangabad Chikalthan Aerodrome

  IndiaBombay / Santacruz

  IndiaBilaspur

  IndiaBhuj-Rudramata

  IndiaBelgaum / Sambra

  IndiaBhopal / Bairagarh

  IndiaBhaunagar

  IndiaGoa / Dabolim Airport

  IndiaIndore

  IndiaJabalpur

  IndiaKhandwa

  IndiaKolhapur

  IndiaNagpur Sonegaon

  IndiaRajkot

  IndiaSholapur

  IndiaAgartala

  IndiaSiliguri

  IndiaBhubaneswar

  IndiaCalcutta / Dum Dum

  IndiaCar Nicobar

  IndiaGorakhpur

  IndiaGauhati

  IndiaGaya

  IndiaImphal Tulihal

  IndiaJharsuguda

  IndiaJamshedpur

  IndiaNorth Lakhimpur

  IndiaDibrugarh / Mohanbari

  IndiaPort Blair

  IndiaPatna

  IndiaM. O. Ranchi

  IndiaAgra

  IndiaAllahabad / Bamhrauli

  IndiaAmritsar

  IndiaVaranasi / Babatpur

  IndiaBareilly

  IndiaKanpur / Chakeri

  IndiaNew Delhi / Safdarjung

  IndiaNew Delhi / Palam

  IndiaGwalior

  IndiaHissar

  IndiaJhansi

  IndiaJodhpur

  IndiaJaipur / Sanganer

  IndiaKota Aerodrome

  IndiaLucknow / Amausi

  IndiaSatna

  IndiaUdaipur Dabok

  IndiaBellary

  IndiaVijayawada / Gannavaram

  IndiaCoimbatore / Peelamedu

  IndiaCochin / Willingdon

  IndiaCuddapah

  IndiaHyderabad Airport

  IndiaMadurai

  IndiaMangalore / Bajpe

  IndiaMadras / Minambakkam

  IndiaTiruchchirapalli

  IndiaThiruvananthapuram

  IndiaVellore


)
```

I was willing to get the same as answer.

Thanks a lot and someone may get help from this post.